# how to ajax upload file in .net?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, file-upload

I need to implement ajax upload functionality similar to the one in [this page](http://www.uploadstills.com) . But I do not want to make a 1000 line code out of it. If anyone knows a simple ajax upload method without using third party tools that would be great.

Comment: The HTML 5 File API (supported by some browsers) is very promising, too: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a "simple" ajax file upload method (without using 3rd party tools), because browsers will not allow javascript to upload files due to security considerations. That could allow malicious web sites to upload your private files.

There are (afaik) two predominant ways of doing it, one is using a flash plug-in, and the other is creating an iframe that handles the upload.

I have previously used this one: https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload which worked well

But there is a new version here that I have not yet tried: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

/Pete